# Composer require issue

Tags: composer-php

This is the [package](https://github.com/hans2103/Kiyoh_Customerreview) , which I want to get with composer. This is my command:

`composer require kiyoh/customerreview`

This is my composer.json file:

```
"repositories": [
        .......
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "git@github.com:hans2103/Kiyoh_Customerreview.git" }
],
"require": {
    "kiyoh/customerreview": "2.1.0.11",
   ......
 }
```

This is the result, what I got in the console:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                            
  Could not find package kiyoh/customerreview at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability .
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`kiyoh/customerreview` does not have any version. Repository contains only master branch and does not have any tags.

To fix it you can replace require part:

```
"require": {
    "kiyoh/customerreview": "dev-master",
   ......
 }
```

it means that composer will use master branch for as source

Additionally you need add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` on top level on your `composer.json`.

Eventually your `composer.json` must looks like this:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": [
        .......
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "git@github.com:hans2103/Kiyoh_Customerreview.git" }
],
"require": {
    "kiyoh/customerreview": "dev-master",
   ......
 }
```